# What is the result of $\frac{h^2}{2}O(h)+O(h^3)$

Tags: asymptotics

Why and how in the following expression
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+hy^{\prime}_n+\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{y^{\prime}_{n+1}-y^{\prime}_n}{h}+O(h) \right]h^2+O(h^3)
$$
$$\Rightarrow
y_{n+1}=y_n+h\left( y^{\prime}_n+\frac{1}{2}y^{\prime}_{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}y^{\prime}_n \right)+O(h^3)
$$
the $O(h)$ term eliminated?

Comment: Because you are multiplying $h^2$ terms of order $O(h)$ which is of $O(h^3).$

Comment: We distribute the product to find $O(h) \cdot h^2 = O(h^3)$, which gets absorbed into the other $H(h^3)$ term

Comment: OMG! Why am I stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's because $h^2O(h)=O(h^3)$.